# Nested JSON parsing in swift, problems with structs

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, parsing

I want to parse a JSON with a nested structure.

I created a couple of structs with the required fields and now trying to use them.

That's how JSON looks like (Eventful API):

```
{
  "last_item": null,
   "total_items": "1194",
   "first_item": null,
   "page_number": "1",
   "page_size": "10",
   "page_items": null,
   "search_time": "0.143",
   "page_count": "120",
   "events": {
     "event": [
       {
         "watching_count": null,
         "olson_path": "Europe/London",
         "calendar_count": null,
         "comment_count": null,
         "region_abbr": "London",
         "postal_code": null,
         "going_count": null,
         "all_day": "0",
         "latitude": "51.5009088",
         "groups": null,
         "url": "http://london.eventful.com/events/zucchero-/E0-001-120935308-6?utm_source=apis&utm_medium=apim&utm_campaign=apic",
         "id": "E0-001-120935308-6",
         "privacy": "1",
         "city_name": "London",
         "link_count": null,
         ...
```

That's that I'm trying to do:

```
struct Event: Codable {

    var id: String
    var title: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var url: URL
    var venueAddress: String
    var regionName: String
    var image: [Image]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
        case latitude
        case longitude
        case url
        case venueAddress = "venue_address"
        case regionName = "region_name"
        case image

}

struct Events: Codable {
    var events: [Event]
}


let apiUrlString = "http://api.eventful.com/json/events/......."
var event = [Event]()   


func parse(json: Data) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        if let jsonEvents = try? decoder.decode(Events.self, from: json) {
            self?.event = jsonEvents.events
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func searchButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let url = URL(string: apiUrlString) {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            parse(json: data)
            print(event)
        } else {
            showError()
        }
    } else {
        showError()
    }
}
```

Parse func works fine, but my array is always empty. I guess that I could make some changes in my Event and Events structs. If you have any suggestions, please help.

Comment: The JSONs events property does not contain an array (`[Event]`) but a dictionay (`[String: [Event]]`). Except of that `latitude` and `longitude` are `String`s, not `Double`s. And since the parsing happens asynchronously you are printing `event` too early.

Comment: The main problem is here, `try? decoder...`. When you use `try?` instead of catching and printing the error you are missing out on vital information for trouble shooting your issue since the json decoding errors are most often very helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Yes, you're right about latitude and longitude, thank you! 
I tried to use a dictionary to store properties, but it's still empty after button tap =(

Answer (score 0):

Here's the model for your json response try this out.

```
// MARK: - Event
struct Event: Codable {
    let lastItem: JSONNull?
    let totalItems: String
    let firstItem: JSONNull?
    let pageNumber, pageSize: String
    let pageItems: JSONNull?
    let searchTime, pageCount: String
    let events: Events

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case lastItem = "last_item"
        case totalItems = "total_items"
        case firstItem = "first_item"
        case pageNumber = "page_number"
        case pageSize = "page_size"
        case pageItems = "page_items"
        case searchTime = "search_time"
        case pageCount = "page_count"
        case events
    }
}

// MARK: - Events
struct Events: Codable {
    let event: [EventElement]
}

// MARK: - EventElement
struct EventElement: Codable {
    let watchingCount: JSONNull?
    let olsonPath: String
    let calendarCount, commentCount: JSONNull?
    let regionAbbr: String
    let postalCode, goingCount: JSONNull?
    let allDay, latitude: String
    let groups: JSONNull?
    let url: String
    let id, privacy, cityName: String
    let linkCount: JSONNull?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case watchingCount = "watching_count"
        case olsonPath = "olson_path"
        case calendarCount = "calendar_count"
        case commentCount = "comment_count"
        case regionAbbr = "region_abbr"
        case postalCode = "postal_code"
        case goingCount = "going_count"
        case allDay = "all_day"
        case latitude, groups, url, id, privacy
        case cityName = "city_name"
        case linkCount = "link_count"
    }
}
```